# Open a .xlsx file with a partly variable name in Python

Tags: python, excel, file

Every day an automatic system creates a .xlsx file. The last 3 files had the following filenames:

- pos_list_13JAN24_r9664140.xlsx
- pos_list_12JAN24_r9664027.xlsx
- pos_list_11JAN24_r9659944.xlsx

As you can see, the last part of the name changes. Now I want to open these files in Python without having to lookup the last part of the file name over and over again.
I know you can do this in Excel by defining the name as: "...\pos_list_" & Date & "*.xlsx"

So I've got the following code, but how do I make it work?

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date 

Date = ((date.today()).strftime("%d%b%y")).upper() 
Input_Path = r'...\\pos_list_' + Date + '*.xlsx' 
df = pd.read_excel(Input_Path, sheet = 'Data')
```

Thanks in advance!

---

**Solution**

Thanks thom747 and vgenovpy for your answers. I think I found a solution. I now have the following code which solves it:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import glob

Date = ((date.today()).strftime("%d%b%y")).upper() 
Input_Path = glob.glob('...\\pos_list_*.xlsx') 
df = pd.read_excel(Input_Path[0], sheet = 'Data')
```

I hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built-in Python [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for this.
Specifically, [Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is not clear for me if this folder is accumulative, in the way that some system adds three files everyday and the folder keeps growing and growing, in any case, I've made a little script for you that will order this list of files by modification date as a **key**, so you can work with the last three.

```py
import os # to get the list of xlsx files

excels = os.listdir("excels") # I just created a folder named excels, name it as you need it
excels.sort(key=lambda mdate: os.path.getmtime(f"ex/{mdate}"), reverse=True) # arranging all files by modification date in reverse (last modified first)
for file in excels[:3]: 
    print(file)
```

Your code + mine should look something like this **(use as a guideline)**:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import os # to get the list of xlsx files

Date = ((date.today()).strftime("%d%b%y")).upper()

excels = os.listdir("excels") # replace **excels** where you have your files
excels.sort(key=lambda mdate: os.path.getmtime(f"ex/{mdate}"), reverse=True) # arranging all files by modification date in reverse (last modified first 
Input_Path = r'...\\pos_list_' + Date + '*.xlsx' 
df = pd.read_excel(Input_Path, sheet = 'Data')

# create df for last three files:
for file_path in excels[:3]: 
    df = pd.read_excel(f"excels/{file_path}", sheet = "Data")
    # Do stuff...
```